# Pulling a Usable Link out of a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I need to figure out how to have a link that I pull from a JSON object an ACTUAL link that the user can click and follow to the site instead of just text. I feel like it's gotta be a quick fix, but I can't seem to figure it out! Thanks for the help!!

```
function sqoot(URL) {
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        method: "GET"
    }).done(function(response) {

        var deals = response.deals
        var untrackedURL = $("#untrackedURL");
        var couponInfo = $("#info");

      for (i = 0; i < deals.length; i++) {
            var newUntrackedURL = $("<a href='deals[i].deal.untracked_url'>" + deals[i].deal.untracked_url + "</a>");
            couponInfo.append(newUntrackedURL)

        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your fetched data is correctly used, here's why your link doesn't work : the href is actually `deals[i].deal.untracked_url` instead of its content.

try this instead :

```
function sqoot(URL) {
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    method: "GET"
}).done(function (response) {
    var deals = response.deals
    var untrackedURL = $("#untrackedURL");
    var couponInfo = $("#info");            

    for (i = 0; i < deals.length; i++) {
        var newUntrackedURL = $('<a href="' + deals[i].deal.untracked_url + '">' + deals[i].deal.untracked_url + "</a>");
        couponInfo.append(newUntrackedURL)
    }
})
};
```

Without the generated JSON, I can't help you further if this solution doesn't helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Look like maybe you had a typo:

**'deals[i].deal.untracked_url'** should be  **'deals["+ i +"].deal.untracked_url'**

```
function sqoot(URL) {
  $.ajax({
  url: URL,
  method: "GET"
}).done(function (response) {

  var deals = response.deals

  var untrackedURL = $("#untrackedURL");


  var couponInfo = $("#info");            

  for (i = 0; i < deals.length; i++) {


      var newUntrackedURL = $("<a href='deals["+ i +"].deal.untracked_url'>" + 
       deals[i].deal.untracked_url + "</a>");
    couponInfo.append(newUntrackedURL)

  }
});
```

Scratch that - you want it to pull the value not write out "deals[i].deal.untracked_url." To do that you do the below.

```
function sqoot(URL) {
  $.ajax({
  url: URL,
  method: "GET"
}).done(function (response) {

  var deals = response.deals

  var untrackedURL = $("#untrackedURL");


  var couponInfo = $("#info");            

  for (i = 0; i < deals.length; i++) {
      var newUntrackedURL = $("<a href='"+deals[i].deal.untracked_url+"'>" + 
       deals[i].deal.untracked_url + "</a>");
    couponInfo.append(newUntrackedURL)

  }
});
```

Comment: should the plusses on either side of the i be inside of those double quotes?